# How insecure is / replacement for tmpnam?

Tags: python, security, qt, pyqt

I considered using `tmpnam` to set the output file name of a `QPrinter`. But the Python documentation recommends against using it.

> ### os.tmpnam()
>
> Return a unique path name that is reasonable for creating a temporary
>   file. ... Applications are responsible
>   for properly creating and managing
>   files created using paths returned by
>   tmpnam(); no automatic cleanup is
>   provided.
>
> > #### Warning
> >
> > Use of tmpnam() is vulnerable to symlink attacks; consider using
> >     tmpfile() (section File Object
> >     Creation) instead.
>
> Windows: Microsoft’s
>   implementation of `tmpnam()` always
>   creates a name in the root directory
>   of the current drive, and that’s
>   generally a poor location for a temp
>   file (depending on privileges, you may
>   not even be able to open a file using
>   this name).

- Is this really insecure if my application doesn't need any special privileges?
- What are secure alternatives considering that I can only set a path as the output file name of the `QPrinter`?

Comment: Security depends on the environment. In a hostile environment it could mean that someone else can get access to the data created by QPrinter. As you read here, on Windows it could mean that you can't get a writable tmpnam. Since tempfile is so easy to use and does the right thing, just use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html

Use that instead.

Comment: Thanks. I don't suppose this creates a big security risk if I get a name using `NamedTemporaryFile` and supply it to `QPrinter`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're supposing.  `tempfile` has the most secure temporary files.  It doesn't really require a supposition; that's what the claim is.  Is there some further question?  Some clarification you need?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your QPrinter deals with a file that already exists, you could use QTemporaryFile to create a file, then close the file and keep the reference to the QTemporaryFile object around until you are done with it.  (This will also clean up the file for you when you destroy the object.)